# Possible to make a PocketMine plugin with Python?

Tags: python, minecraft, pocketmine

Is it possible to create a plugin on PocketMine with Python? If not, is there any way you could?

Answer (score 2):

> To fully understand this tutorial, and develop plugins, you require
>   basic knowledge of the PHP programming language.

Based on this quote from the wiki, PocketMine plugins are written in PHP, so it is unlikely you will be able to use Python.

https://github.com/PocketMine/Documentation/wiki/Plugin-Tutorial

---

Original answer left for reference:

> http://forums.pocketmine.net/forums/plugin-development.11/
>
> Based on the tutorial, it appears they use PHP. Have you asked in the
>   forums?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13745927)

Comment: I don't agree that this was a link only-answer, as my original answer states that they use PHP, but I have expanded the answer slightly.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Your original answer was more like a comment and the link was the main content. Now its fine, you have my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't.
PocketMine is written in PHP, which means you need to write your plugins in PHP.
either you rewrite the software in python?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a PocketMine plugin that provides an adapter interface to a Python process. It can run a said plugin in Python in the background, and send events, commands and timers into the Python process through inter-process communication techniques like STDIN/STDOUT communication. The main issue is that it would require a higher degree of async support in PocketMine events, which is right now still insufficient.